# Window.location - javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php, popup

I've create in my php programme a piece of code:

```
$dest = 'https://www.google.com';

$stay = 'currenturl';
          echo '<pre>'; 
          echo "<script language=\"javascript\">";
          echo "    window.location = '". $stay."';";
          echo "    var win = null;";
          echo "    LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-995)/2 : 0;";
          echo "    TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-640)/2 : 0;";
          echo "    settings = 'height=500,width=600,top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,status=yes';";
          echo "    win = window.open('" . $dest . "','network',settings);";
          echo "</script>"; 
          echo '</pre>';    
          exit;
```

If I run this code it will open my pop up window, which is google, and refresh (because it's the only idea I've got which allow me to stay on the same page - otherwise it goes blank...) current page. I want to avoid refreshing and stay on the same page.

Do you know how to change this "window.location" to achieved it?

Answer (score 0):

mate, you should not use php code to open a new window by injecting js script, that's why you are going to another page as the php code ouput new content to the current page, you should have all your logic about new window in a JavaScript function. then you should stay on the same page

Comment: so could you help me with that? link or smth ? Im green in javascript